# Using Threads in android games

Tags: android, multithreading, garbage

I've been reading stuff about android game development and performance optimization.
And i have two questions:

Supose i have a game, and in that game i use one thread for drawing stuff on a canvas. when I fire a bullet i want an explosion to happen at contact with another surface. will the game wait for the explosion to render and then continue to render the rest of the animations etc?
or will it all happen at the same time?

The second question is about the garbage collector, and if anyone could give me some hints or post a link to something about it regardin games performance.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would split the garbage collection and the multithreading into separate questions... frankly the garbage question collection would probably be closed for being too vague, but so make sure that you are very specific about what you're asking. As it is, even this question is too general and I doubt that you would get a meaningful answer.

Comment: You're right... I thought maybe someone could give me an equally vague answer : D

Comment: how will a vague question and a vague answer be helpful to anybody, and more importantly: how will it be helpful to you?

Comment: well tou could say:"yes, it will all be rendered at the same time" or "no, the game will wait until the explosion finishes to render before continuing"

or even "the garbage collector generally cleans leftover objects, one thing you could do is to try and (insert advice), have a look at (insert link)"... 

I don't think that's asking too much.... : \

Comment: I'm just trying to help you get the most value out of your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will the game wait for the explosion to render and then continue to render the rest of the animations etc?

Not unless you do something to specifically make the game wait for the events to execute in a certain order. If you have synchronized access to the canvas, then all that will be guaranteed is that the two threads will not draw on the canvas at the same time, but the order in which they draw, and when they draw, is not guaranteed.

> or will it all happen at the same time?

The order in which the drawing will occur may be concurrent, so you could say it's happening in the same time. However, it's recommended that [only one thread draws on the canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568616/android-concurrent-access-to-the-canvas-safely).

If I were you I would try to get a decent [2D/3D game engine for android](http://www.google.com/search?q=android%203D%20game%20engine%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) and worry about your game more than the multithreading and garbage collection behind it.